# Export Excel table or named range to Access using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, export

I have the following code that I am using to insert values from an Excel sheet to an Access table. It works

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strQuery As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn

.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Excel\testdb.accdb;"
.Open
End With

ssql = "INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$]"
```

I know that I can also do the same with a specified range by doing the following:

```
ssql = "INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]"
```

However, after trying everything and looking everywhere, I can't figure out how to do this for an Excel table or named range.Is it possible? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

actually, I was able to do it by:

```
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].range_name"
```

The problem I was having before was that the Excel table I was using was created by a connection to external data (actually the same Access database). I tried to import and link to the Excel table from Access and was only able to do so when the Excel file was closed. I guess this is to prevent some kind of circular referencing.

Comment: Still, you are able to import or link to a table in an open Excel file if you just select the worksheet that the table is on. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Umm... how is this different from the complete answer I gave you? From what you wrote, it is obvious that you are using a named range scoped to the workbook.

Comment: I edited my original question. At first, my question had the same Excel file in the connection string. What I really wanted was the link to an Access database. So in my SQL, "Table1" is actually an Access table. The way the queries in your response are formatted, I don't know if VBA would have been able to distinguish between an Access table and an Excel named range.

Comment: The first part of my answer is just a comment. That can be ignored since you changed your question. Your question is about how to reference the named range. I gave you the syntax, which you are using in your own answer. The syntax is dependent on the type of named range. My answer gives the solution to both types.

Comment: Perhaps you should have taken the time to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the workbook again in the WHERE clause since it is already referenced in the connection string.

To answer your question, the scope of the defined name determines the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM [YourSheetName$SheetScopedNamedRange]
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM WorkbookScopedNamedRange
```

Note hat there are no square brackets in the second example.